`headers` was called outside a request scope
Im trying to create a temporary session in my API using nextJS version 14.2.3, this session needs to be created using a API-KEY and Bearer Token comming from the headers, but im getting this error, heres the code im trying to use:
`import { ApiError } from '@/lib/errors';
import { throwIfNoAccessToApiKey } from '@/lib/guards/team-api-key'; // Adjust the import path based       on your project structure
import { throwIfNoTeamAccess } from 'models/team';
import { getOrders } from 'models/order';
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
import NextAuth  from 'next-auth';

import { getAuthOptions } from '@/lib/nextAuth';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    const session = await getServerSession(getAuthOptions(req, res));
    console.log("SESSION: ", session)

    const { teamId } = await throwIfNoTeamAccess(req, res);
    console.log("TEAM ID: ", teamId)
    switch (req.method) {
      case 'GET':
        await handleGET(req, res, teamId);
        break;
      default:
        res.setHeader('Allow', 'GET, POST, DELETE, PATCH');
        res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
    }
  } catch (error: any) {
    const message = error.message || 'Something went wrong';
    const status = error.status || 500;
    res.status(status).json({ error: { message } });
  }
}`


Please add error message that you received, also add any other information that may be helpful like API call & its parameters.
